# Broke the Login Screen on OpenSuse Tumblweed after removing packages

Tags: opensuse

I mindlessly removed some packages which I should not have removed, these packages are:

```
btrfsmaintenance dejavu-fonts desktop-data-openSUSE docbook_4 efont-unicode-bitmap-fonts fonts-config ghostscript-fonts-other ghostscript-fonts-std ghostscript-fonts-std-converted google-carlito-fonts google-poppins-fonts gtk2-branding-openSUSE gtk2-metatheme-adwaita gtk3-metatheme-adwaita hicolor-icon-theme hicolor-icon-theme-branding-openSUSE intlfonts-euro-bitmap-fonts intltool iso_ent issue-generator libBasicUsageEnvironment1 libcfitsio9 libesmtp6 libglslang11 libgmp10-32bit libgraphite2-3-32bit libgssdp-1_2-0-32bit libgupnp-1_2-0-32bit libgupnp-igd-1_0-4 libjbig2-32bit libKF5Screen7 libkgantt-lang libldac2-32bit liblmdb-0_9_29 liblockdev1-32bit libmarkdown2 libmtdev1-32bit libnscd1-32bit libproxy1-config-kde-32bit libqgpgme7 libqpdf28 libraw20 libre2-9 libreoffice-share-linker libsbc1-32bit libsrt1_4 libtiff5 libts0-32bit libunistring2 libwebrtc_audio_processing1-32bit libZXing1 man-pages-posix media-player-info metatheme-adwaita-common parallel-printer-support perl-biber python38-cmdln python38-dbus-python python38-decorator python38-gobject python38-gobject-cairo python38-gobject-Gdk python38-ipaddr python38-notify2 python38-pycairo python38-six python38-slip python38-slip-dbus qemu-ipxe sound-theme-freedesktop system-user-mktex wallpaper-branding-openSUSE xdg-menu xorg-x11-essentials yast2-trans-stats
```

Now, I reinstalled them after noticing that it was not a good idea, but seemingly it was to late, since I get a login screen looking like this now
[image]

I would like to get it back to its previous look, as seen in the picture below:

[image]

In the picture above, the lock screen with its original look appears after I have initially logged in. The problem (the old-looking login screen) only shows up when login in for the first time.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sure, I will update the post.